# How to get log messages to display in Spock Reports?

Tags: spock, geb, spock-reports

I am using the Spock Reports extension in a Geb test. I am trying to find if there is any way to get the logging messages to display in the Spock report.

I have something roughly like this:

```
@Slf4j
class SpockReportExample extends GebReportingSpec {

    def expectedVar = "5"

    when: "I click the button."
    button.click()

    then: "The new value is displayed."
    def value = formElement.value()
    value==expectedValue
    log.info("The new value is $value")

}
```

I'd like to see the the log stating the actual value to be output in my spock report, but I can't find a way. I've tried sending the log at info, warning, debug, error, and trace levels but no luck. Is this possible?

Comment: You are supposed to see the entry in the report. Find the `index.html` click to the standard output tab.

Comment: When I go to index.html and click on my test, I do not see the logging messages. I also do not see a "standard output tab." Is there a specific report template that has this feature?

Comment: Do you have a navigator to the tests them self? it's a link, should be in green or red

Comment: I am using the default Spock Reports template. When I click the red or green link to the specific feature spec it just dispays

When: I click the button.
Then: The new value is displayed.

Comment: can you share your project?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to use Athaydes Spock Reports you can write messages to the report by using

```
reportInfo "This is a message"
```

See https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports#how-to-use-it

This is possible since V1.4.0

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `@Slf4j` just use `println`. spock, junit, and so on capture standard out and add it to the test results.

Comment: Depends on what you are referring to, the spock built-in reporting does capture it. If you mean some third party library then you should clarify that.

Comment: The name of the extension is Spock Reports. I will specify that it's an extension above.